# Possible to re-use one field multiple times in a section?

Tags: dry

This seems like it should be possible but I may be missing a trick.

Is it possible to use a single field multiple times in a section? So, for example, if you have a simple 'text' field and you want to include that twice in one section. The field layout designer only allows you to drag it once and then just move it to different tabs but not create another *instance* of it.

Answer (score 4):

You can re-use the same text field multiple times in a section on different Entry Types, but if you would like to re-use the same text field multiple times on the same Entry Type (or page) your best bet would be to make it a Matrix Block.

For a quick overview on Matrix Blocks: https://craftcms.com/features/matrix

More info on Matrix Blocks: https://craftcms.com/docs/matrix-fields